# MDX using except doesn't work

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, mdx, except

I have the following Problem:

```
Select
    {
        [Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd]

    } on columns,

    Non Empty{  
       Except(([Desk].[DeskName].[Trade].Members,[Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10]),([Desk].[DeskName].[Trade].Members,[Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[09]))
    } on rows

from [Cube]

where ([Entity].[Entity].&[9], [Audience].[View].&[GOD])
```

It exists a Dimension with the Name Desk. This Dimension has a Hierarchy with the name DeskName. The lowest Level ist Trade.

Desk: -Total -Segment -BusinessArea -Department -4th Level Portfolio -Desk -Trade

With the Query showing below, i want to show all Trades, that have the Measure "PerformanceTotalYtd" != NULL on the Date of 2012/01/10  except the Trades with the Measure "PerformanceTotalYtd" != NULL on the Date of 2012/01/09 !

Example:

Trades with Measure PerformanceTotalYtd on the 2012/01/10:

ABC 12,99

DEF  3,22

GHI 55,60

Trades with Measure PerformanceTotalYtd on the 2012/01/09:

ABC 80,00

DEF  8,78

I want the following Result because the Trade "GHI" doesn't exists on the 2012/01/09 and is new:

GHI 55,60

My Query showing below have this result:

ABC 12,99

DEF  3,22

GHI 55,60

It doesn't delete the existing Trades from the 2012/01/09.

I have a Solution in SQL but want to make it in MDX:

```
    SELECT DD.Code, Sum(PerformanceTotalYtd) as TOTAL
      FROM [Reporting_DB].[Star].[Fact_PerformanceTotal] FIS
            inner join Star.Dimension_Desk DD on FIS.DeskID = DD.DeskID
      WHERE FIS.TimeID = 20120110 and FIS.EntityID = 9 AND DD.Code not in ( SELECT DD.Code
FROM [Reporting_DB_HRE].[Star].[Fact_PerformanceTotal] FIS inner join Star.Dimension_Desk DD on FIS.DeskID = DD.DeskID WHERE FIS.TimeID = 20120109 and FIS.EntityID = 9 group by DD.Code)group by DD.Code
```

Can anybody help me please? I can't find a solution.

Sorry for my bad english!

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a similar example in the Adventure Works cube:
The set `{[Customer].[City].&[Bell Gardens]&[CA], [Customer].[City].&[Bellevue]&[WA], [Customer].[City].&[Bellflower]&[CA]}` has 3 values for `[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]` in `[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2002]`, and only 2 values in `[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2004]`. So we need to show measure value for member in 2002 where measure value == null in 2004.
The next MDX query achieves the desired result:

```
with set S as '{[Customer].[City].&[Bell Gardens]&[CA], [Customer].[City].&[Bellevue]&[WA], [Customer].[City].&[Bellflower]&[CA]}'
select
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on 0,
non empty { Filter(S, IsEmpty(([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2004], [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]))) } on 1
from [Adventure Works]
where ([Date].[Calendar Year].&[2002])
```

I tried to modify your example accordingly, but can't test it. Here it is:

```
select
{ [Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd] } on 0,
non empty { Filter([Desk].[DeskName].[Trade].Members, IsEmpty(([Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[09], [Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd]))) } on 1
from [Cube]
where ([Entity].[Entity].&[9], [Audience].[View].&[GOD], [Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10])
```

In short: use Filter instead of Except.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! :) Later I will post a Solution with the Except Statement! I can do it after 8 hours after my post writing!

Answer (score 1):

I have the Solution for my Problem. Following Query shows the same Result as the Query of Dmitry Polyanitsa!  Have a nice Day guys!

```
with
    set [Trades Today] as NonEmpty([Desk].[DeskName].[Trade].Members,  ([Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd], [Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[10]))
    set [Trades Yesterday] as NonEmpty([Desk].[DeskName].[Trade].Members,  ([Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd], [Time].[Year-Month-Day].[Day].&[2012]&[1]&[9]))
    set [Trades Difference] as Except([Trades Today], [Trades Yesterday])

Select
    {
        [Measures].[PerformanceTotalYtd]

    } on columns,

    Non Empty{  
       [Trades Difference]
    } on rows

from [Cube]

where ([Entity].[Entity].&[9], [Audience].[View].&[GOD])
```